# How to insert a table at the beginning of a docx document using NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, npoi

I am trying to use NPOI to insert a new table at the beginning of an existing docx Word document.  Here is what the code looks like:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\input.docx", FileMode.Open);
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(fs);

        XWPFTable table = new XWPFTable(new CT_Tbl(), doc, 2, 2);
        var par = table.GetRow(0).GetCell(0).AddParagraph();
        var run = new XWPFRun(new CT_R(), (IRunBody) par);
        run.AppendText("The quick brown fox was here.");
        par.AddRun(run);

        doc.InsertTable(0, table);

        FileStream output = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\output.docx", FileMode.Create);

        doc.Write(output);

        output.Close();
        fs.Close();
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  The string and table are nowhere to be found in output.docx.  Does anyone have any idea why?

I'm not too sure what a CT_R or CT_Tbl are, or how to make one, so perhaps that ias part of the issue.  With little to no documentation, hoping someone out there has experience with this popular NuGet library.

Note: Other examples show how to add a table at the end of a doc, but not the beginning.

Comment: Any specific reason you using the NPOI library if there is little to no documentation?
Maybe have a look at xceed Docx. its free and works well.
Lots of examples and info on the web.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocX/

Comment: @PieterAlberts I did try docx but I noticed it doesn't support the older doc format, which our customer wants to support.  What is frustrating here is POI has lots of docs but NPOI but has no docs and is weirdly different than POI

Comment: Any reason you're not using the Open XML SDK? That supports the complete "object model" (many other libraries only support "popular" actions) and is fully documented.